# Allow locale switching Rails I18n HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, rails-i18n

I want to get the language of non sign in user from the browser for this i have this code in my application controller

```
  def set_locale
    if user_signed_in? && !current_user.language.blank?
        I18n.locale = current_user.language
    else
      I18n.locale = extract_locale_from_accept_language_header

      if user_signed_in? && current_user.language.blank?
        current_user.language = I18n.locale
        current_user.save
      end
    end
  end

  def default_url_options(options={})
    { :locale => I18n.locale }
  end

  private

  def extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
    preferred_language = request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] || ''
    preferred_language = preferred_language.scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
    available_locales= ("en" "fr")
    if available_locales.include?(preferred_language)
      preferred_language
    else
      "en"
    end
  end
```

Suppose that my Browser language is french this give me `http://localhost:3000/fr` but the problem is when a non sign in user change language to English  and go to another page for example `http://localhost:3000/en/users/sign_up` the language will change to French so i get `http://localhost:3000/fr/users/sign_up` and not `http://localhost:3000/en/users/sign_up` so I'm wondering how can i solve this problem

This is my route file

Update

```
scope :path => ":locale" do
.......
 end

# Catch all requests without a locale and redirect to the default...
  get '*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}"), constraints: lambda { |req| !req.path.starts_with? "/#{I18n.default_locale}/" }
  get '', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}")
```

Comment: Please do not deface your posts. Content on Stack Overflow is intended to help *everyone*, not just you.

Comment: Further, if you wish to be disassociated from your content (for whatever reason) you can either flag your post for moderator attention, using the 'custom'/'other' flag (who can't disassociate the content, but they *can* contact a developer/SE employee to have them do so), or you can [contact the team](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) directly, to have them do so on your behalf.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would fix your issue:

```
  def set_locale
    if user_signed_in? && !current_user.language.blank?
        I18n.locale = current_user.language
    else
      I18n.locale = if params[:locale].present?
                      params[:locale] # Here you might want to do some checking to allow only your desired locales
                    else
                      extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
                    end

      if user_signed_in? && current_user.language.blank?
        current_user.language = I18n.locale
        current_user.save
      end
    end
  end
```

This will give precedence to a specified locale in the URL (`en` | `fr`) over the `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` header.

Comment: But this will always give me http://localhost:3000/en when trying to access http://localhost:3000/ even if my Browser language is French

Comment: It shouldn't. If you access localhost:3000, then `params[:locale]` won't be present, and then it will run the extract_locale method giving you french if your browser is set to use such language.

Comment: If you get redirected to `/en`, then there is something that is setting the `locale` param elsewhere, for example the `routes.rb` file.